# Intermingled input when using local gpg-agent from remote site

Tags: ssh, tty, gpg, gpg-agent, pinentry

I'm starting a local `gpg-agent` on my Mac, with the `extra-socket` option. Then I connect to a remote site using SSH, forwarding the remote `S.gpg-agent` socket to the local `S.gpg-agent.extra` socket. This works:

```
ssh -R /remotehome/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/localhome/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra remotesystem
```

When I want to sign something on the remote machine, the `pinentry` dialog pops up locally and asks for the password, which is the way it should work. However, when I start typing my password, some of the key presses obviously goes into `pinentry` (they are displayed as `*`) whereas some key presses ends up in the shell that runs on the same tty as the `pinentry` process.

```
     ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
     │ Note: Request from a remote site.                              │
     │                                                                │
     │ Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:  │
     │ "My name  <my.email@address>"                                  │
     │ 4096-bit RSA key, ID MYKEYIDXXX0000YYY,                        │
     │ created 2015-06-17 (main key ID MYMAINKEYIDXXX0000YYY).        │
     │                                                                │
     │                                                                │
     │ Passphrase: t*i*e_____________________________________________ │
     │                                                                │
     │         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       │
     └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> has a chance of either sending the mangled password to `gpg`, or sending whatever key presses that didn't go into `pinentry` to the shell:

`/bin/ksh: tie: not found`

How do I get `pinentry` to grab *all* keys from the tty?

The local machine is a Mac running GnuPG 2.1.14 (compiled from `pkgsrc`). The remote site is either a Linux machine with the same version of GnuPG or an OpenBSD machine with GnuPG version 2.1.15 (no difference). The `extra-socket` option is the only option enabled in my `gpg-agent.conf`. The environment variable `GPG_TTY` is correctly set, and running `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye` locally will move the tty on which `pinentry` starts up, but with the same problem.

Doing `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye` on the remote machine results in

`$ gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
gpg-connect-agent: connection to agent is in restricted mode
ERR 67109115 Forbidden <GPG Agent>`

... which is what I kinda expect should happen.

Changing from the curses interface to the tty interface for `pinentry` makes no difference. These are the only two `pinentry` interfaces available to me.  I do not run X11.

---

Update: With the local system running OpenBSD 6.3 (GnuPG 2.2.9) and the remote being some Ubuntu system (GnuPG 2.1.11), it's even worse with *no* key presses going into `pinentry` and everything being read by the shell.