# GPG pinentry not receiving key presses during passphrase entry when forwarding gpg-agent

Tags: linux, gpg, macos, gpg-agent, pinentry

When forwarding my gpg-agent to a remote server I am able to see the my private key listed.
Even though I unlocked my key locally I still need to unlock it on the remote machine.

However when I try to unlock on the remote machine it sends a pinentry to my local machine.
When using `pinentry-tty` or `pinentry-curses` I am unable to enter my password.

It has some strange behaviour that it receives some keystrokes and some are even shown as plain text.

```
pinentry --version
pinentry-curses (pinentry) 1.1.0
```

Local

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
```

Remote

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12
```

These are my local config files:

`gpg-agent.conf`

```
extra-socket /run/users/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

`ssh.config`

```
Host remote
    HostName <ip-address>
    User <username>
    RemoteForward /run/users/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent /run/users/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

Also on the remote server I added `StreamLocalBindUnlink` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

To 'force' pinentry to show up on a certain terminal locally I had to use the command

```
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
```

As soon as I try to sign something on the remote server I get the following screen on my local terminal

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Note: Request from a remote site.                              │
│                                                                │
│ Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:  │
│ "username <email>"                                             │
│ 256-bit EDDSA key, ID 1234567890,                              │
│ created 2021-01-01.                                            │
│                                                                │
│                                                                │
│ Passphrase: __________________________________________________ │
│                                                                │
│         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

When I try to enter my password I get the following:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Note: Request from a remote site.                              │
│                                                                │
│ Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:  │
│ "username <email>"                                             │
│ 256-bit EDDSA key, ID 1234567890,                              │
│ created 2021-01-01.                                            │
│                                                                │
│                                                                │
│ Passphrase: *elo w**wd    ____________________________________ │
│                                                                │
│         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

When I close out of pinentry I can see part of the plain text on the command line

```
> elo wd
```

Same behaviour when I use `pinentry-tty`.

On my local machine I run Arch Linux but also the same behaviour exists on macos.
For my terminal emulator I use `simple terminal` and `iterm2` respectively.

The remote machine runs Debian Buster.

I would like to keep using `pinentry-tty` or `pinentry-curses`.

Also would it be possible to 'unlock' my gpg private key locally and have that forwarded to remote instead of having to unlock it on the remote server?

Edit:

Seems the exact same thing has been asked over 4 years ago!

[Intermingled input when using local gpg-agent from remote site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325021/intermingled-input-when-using-local-gpg-agent-from-remote-site)

With no answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have the SAME issue in MacOS.

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.34

$ pinentry --version
pinentry-curses (pinentry) 1.2.0
```

In the SAME iTerm window. Run:

```
$ killall gpg-agent && gpg-agent --daemon --pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry
```

Then run a quick test:

```
$ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

The issue is caused by `pinentry` is limited on the SAME terminal window.